# WordPress installation error "access denied"

Tags: wordpress

I am installing WordPress on my Localhost but i am not redirecting to my WordPress installation. I am using xampp server and WordPress version 4.0.

It shows access denied in browser when i try to open my WordPress installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go To Xampp > PhpMyAdmin > and edit Config.inc.php with your favorite editor.

It will look like the below code , just change the ***$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'Password';*** to ***$cfg['Servers'][$i][''] = '';*** and hit save.

```
        $cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'localhost';
        $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
        $cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '';
        $cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
        $cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
        $cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
        $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
        $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
        $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'PasswordWillBeHere';
        $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
```

Comment: No just change the password = '' empty , this code will be available in config.inc.php

Comment: Thank you  you took out from a great trouble thanks alot